# Azure Data Factory v2 parameters for connection string

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am new to using Azure Data Factory v2 and have a few questions regarding general transforming connection strings / LinkedServices when deploying to multiple environments.

## Coming from SSIS background:

we used to define connection strings as project parameters. This allowed transforming the connecting string when deploying the artifacts onto different environments.

How can I accomplish the same using Azure Data Factory v2 ?
Is there an easy way to do this ?

I was trying to set up linked services with connection strings as parameters which then could be passed along with the triggers?  Is this feasible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is now avaialble from URL below.  Are you the one who requested the feature? :)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/parameterize-connections-to-your-data-stores-in-azure-data-factory/

Comment: haha. I did not request the feature. I completely forgot about this question. I ended up solving this problem using a Azure Key Vault per environment.

Comment: accepting the answer. coz you are right. this is the solution for the question I asked. however looking back I would want to avoid an implementation that involves parameters in my connection string :)

Answer (score 0):

Relating to `SSIS` (where we would use configuration files - `.dtsconfig` for deployment to different deployments), for `ADFV2` (& `ADFV1` too) we could look into the option of using `ARM` templates where for every different environment (dev, test & prod) to deploy the `ADF` solution that many deployment files(`.json`) could be made and script the deployments using `PowerShell`. It is possible to use ARM template parameters to parameterize connections to linked services and other environment specific values. Then there are `ADFV2` specific `PowerShell cmdlets` for creation/deployment of `ADFV2` pipelines.

Also you can use `PowerShell` to parametrize connections to `linked services` and other environment specific values.

With the `ADFV2 UI` the `VSTS GIT` integration is possible so is the  deployment and integration. `VSTS GIT` integration allows to choose a feature/development branch or create a new one in the `VSTS GIT` repository. Once the changes are merged with the master branch it could be published to data factory using `ADFV2 UI`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue with setting up an azure key vault per environment each having a connection string secret (more details here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault)

```
- dev
    - dev-azure-datafactory
    - dev-key-vault
     - key: db-conn-string
       value: dev-db.windows.net
- qa
    - qa-azure-datafactory
    - qa-key-vault
     - key: db-conn-string
       value: qa-db.windows.net

- production
    - prod-azure-datafactory
    - prod-key-vault
     - key: db-conn-string
       value: prod-db.windows.net
```

In Azure Data Factory

- Define an Azure Key Vault linked service
- Use the azure key vault linked service while defining connection string(s) for other linked services
- This approach removes any changing of parameters in the actual linked service
- The connection string with azure key vault linked service can be changed as part of your azure pipeline deployment  (more details here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment)
- Each azure data factory can be given access to its azure key vault using MSI (automated it with terraform in our case)